# Inference about heterogeneity of sample from normal population looking at covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

consider:

$Y_1,\dots,Y_n  \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ iid.

If I have a high variance I will see a very heterogenous sample and a large bell around the mean. It is sufficient to look at $\sigma^2$ to have an idea about it.

Now consider:

$\mathbf{Y_1},\dots,\mathbf{Y_n} \sim N_p(\mathbf{0},\Sigma)$.

My question is simple:

**How do I infer the 'heterogeneity' of samples by looking at the covariance matrix?**

Is it possible to say something in general by looking for example at the determinant of the matrix (not considering the $p=2$ case)? 
Or should I just look at the single entries of the matrix?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heterogeneity is large variance? 
If so, then for $Y$ that is MVN with $\Sigma$ as a covariance matrix, its main diagonal is the variance of each component of $Y$, where the non-diagonal terms are covariance of $y_i$ and $y_j$, as such they can be very "large" due to high variance or/and strong correlation. Besides, any judgment as large or small depends on your application. Looking at its determinant can be useful for some purposes as $|\Sigma| = \prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$ when the eigenvalues can give you some indication of the dominant elements.

Comment: I realized that my question is not well posed, because even I don't know what I mean with heterogeneity. My question would be more like: **ok, in a univariate case, by looking at the variance I know how data are dispersed around mean. Is there something in the covariance matrix which gives me the same information?**

Nice insight about the fact that strong covariance components may be such because of high variance of each one of them even if not correlated. 

Could you expand about *when the eigenvalues can give you some indication of the dominant elements?*

Thank you :)

Comment: You can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Intuition) explanation to understand the intuition behind it.